# <hr> tag not working in email template for outlook 2013

Tags: email, outlook, newsletter

I have developed an email template. Everything is working fine in my email template except the `hr` tag in Outlook 2013.

I have attached images

Result which i am getting:

[image: Result which i am getting]

Result which i want:

[image: Result which i want]

Please help me with suitable codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<hr>` is inconsistently supported in email clients. It's easier to do a horizontal rule in email by using a `<table>` tag, something like this:

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="background:black; height:1px;>
      <tr>
           <td style="font-size:0; line-height:0;">
                &nbsp;
           </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

It might seem like a lot of code for simple `<hr>`, but you'll get the best email client coverage by using `<table>`s.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the layout showed strange horizontal lines on Outlook 2010-2019.

To avoid that, this code works for me:

```
<!--[if mso]>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
 <tr width="100%">                                  
  <td width="100%" style="width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; padding-bottom: 1px;">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<hr align="left" style="border: 0px; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; color: #ffffff; background: #ffffff; margin: 0px;"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `<hr>` in email clients is the following, which produces a similar effect, i.e., a thin horizontal line:

```
<div style="background: #d9d9d9; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

This has been verified to render properly in Outlook 2016, but should also work in 2013.